# Prepositional phrases in sentence subjects:"The level of maturity in argument here is astounding.”

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, prepositional-phrases

We’re having a disagreement about the propriety of a prepositional phrase inside the subject of a sentence, as it’s complicated by the presence of a second prepositional phrase, namely “here.”

Simply–is the following a complete, grammatical, proper English sentence as written?

> The level of maturity in argument here is astounding.

Prompted by this specific sentence, but more generally on the propriety of two prepositional phrases back-to-back, is in “…in argument here…,” especially since the first is explaining essence, and being applied to what comes before it (“level of maturity”), while the second directs the reader to a specific place and does not refer back in the same way to what comes before (“here”).

Comment: Is your question whether two prepositional phrases can occur within a subject? Or is it something specific to this sentence?

Comment: Prompted by this specific sentence, but more generally on the propriety of two prepositional phrases back-to-back, is in “…in argument here…,” especially since the first is explaining essence, and being applied to what comes before it (“level of maturity”), while the second directs the reader to a specific place and does not refer back in the same way to what comes before (“here”).

Comment: Are you suggesting that "here" is a prepositional phrase? If so, what definition of PP are you using?

Comment: Collins includes 'in dispute' and M-W 'in contention' ['being argued over' sense], but neither includes 'in argument'. But I needed to check. I'm encouraged in my assumption that the sentence means 'The level of maturity which is displayed in argumentation here is astounding.' I'd use the expanded version to clarify. // the sentence corresponds therefore to 'The size of the flowers on the rhododendrons here is incredible.' I can't see where a problem would arise.

Comment: You can stick as many prepositional phrases or adverbs of place (or time) together as you like "bring it up here round the back behind the shed now" "the train went down northwards into the tunnel" etc.

Comment: I find the wording "level of maturity" a bit strange, because *the maturity of argument* would do the same job more eloquently: *the maturity of argument here is astounding*.

Answer (score 3):

> *The level of maturity in argument here is astounding.*

Your example is fine.

"Here" is an intransitive locative preposition (*in this place*) contrasting with "there".

Its function is that of post-head modifier: it modifies the nominal "level of maturity in argument".

Comment: Recently you called something an ascriptive clause, IIRC, and said that it was not a modifier. You made a distinction between those things. Would it be possible to see **here** as a form of ascription, ascribing location to "The level of maturity in argument"? I am not really clear on the precise definition of "modifier".

Answer (score 0):

An analogue of your sentence:

> Don't go to Jimmy's Pre-Owned Vehicles.  **The quality of the cars on the lot there is questionable**.

P.S. I think **there** applies to "the cars on the lot".

Comment: Yes: the locative preposition "there" (_in that place_) contrasts with the locative prep "here" (_in this place_).

Comment: Your "answer" is a comment; it does not justify the grammar of the initial sentence. It will appear to any reader familiar enough with English that it is a correct sentence, but that is far from a statement that could be explicited from your answer.

Comment: @LPH I don't recognize transitive verb "explicited" and am not sure what you meant.

Comment: @LPH TimR's answer is fine. The distal preposition "there" contrasts with the proximal preposition "here". Both are intransitive, i.e. a complement is not obligatory.

Comment: @TimR Apparently, you are right: the verb "to explicit" is not in my dictionaries. However , there is a full page of instances of use of "[explicited](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22explicited%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" in Google books. What I meant was "made explicit".

Comment: @BillJ I don't think so, and I think that there'll be other readers to make the same remark.

Comment: @LPH:  Do you take OP's question to be about the proper placement of **here**? That it should perhaps be placed after **astounding**? OP didn't elaborate on the supposed "complications" of its current placement.

Comment: "There" does not apply to "the cars on the lot" but to "Jimmy's Pre-Owned Vehicles", the place where the lot is found.

Comment: @LPH:  **there** might refer anaphorically on a semantic level to "Jimmy's Pre-Owned Vehicles" but it applies grammatically, in clause structure, to the preceding noun-phrase, IMO.

Comment: That is another question, and you seem to be giving into user BillJ's point of view; however you answer does give a reasoning that could lead to this conclusion; I must repeat (in other terms): you are merely mentioning a construction.

Comment: @LPH:  If I said "Don't go to JPV. The quality of the cars on the lot *at that place* is questionable" would you see that prepositional phrase as being altogether different from **there**?  **that** is deictic in the same way, no?

Comment: @LPH Yes "there" is anaphoric in that it refers to "Jimmy's Pre-Owned Vehicles", but "there" is still a preposition, an intransitive one, just as "here" is in the OP's example.

Comment: @TimR Not contesting that except that "that" is not deictic: Unless otherwise specified, spatial deictical terms are generally understood to be relative to the location of the speaker, as in "_The shop is across the street._".

    The shop is across the street.

Comment: @LPH: Demonstratives  have long been considered deictic. They express a  closeness or distance and those terms needn't be confined to three-dimensional space. Figurative "attitudinal" distance can be involved.  *I would steer you away from **that** used car lot.*

Answer (score -1):

"Here" is not a prepositional phrase in this construction; it is an adverbial of place that fulfills the additional function of deictic pro-form, more specifically called "*reference signal*". "Here" could be replaced by a prepositional phrase of the type "in this paragraph", "in this sentence", "in these deductions", etc.; the deictic function would then be taken up by the demonstrative.

"Here" does not constitute a phrase with "the level of maturity in argument". This can be seen from the mobility of this word, which is typical of adverbials; all three constructions below have the same meaning and "here" is the same word with the same function.

- *Here* the level of maturity in argument is astounding.
- The level of maturity in argument *here* is astounding.
- The level of maturity in argument is astounding *here*.

> (**CoGEL 19.46**) **Discourse reference**
> There are numerous signals marking the identity between what is being said
> and what has been said before. […] We concentrate here on devices
> that have a special value in referring less to concrete entities than to
> constituents or aspects of discourse itself. The signals can be divided into two
> groups, […]:
> (a) sentence or clause reference signals
> (b) noun-phrase reference signals

> (**CoGEL 19.47**) **Clausal reference**
> Common signals for sentence or clause reference include:
> anaphoric and cataphoric: *here, it, this*

> (**CEG, R. Carter & M. McCarthy, 2006**) **Deixis** (adjective = deictic) A term for words or expressions that depend for their interpretation on the immediate external situation in which they are uttered.
> Deictic words are orientational features and are typically realised by
> determiners (a, the, this, that, these, those), adverbs (here, there), personal pronouns (I, you, them).

Comment: You're conflating word class and function. Preposition is a word class (POS), while adverbial is a function. "Here" is an intransitive preposition modifying "level of maturity in argument.

Comment: Hm... _This **here** is astounding_ / _**Here** this is astounding_ / _This is astounding **here**_. There surely is a difference here.

Comment: @BillJ 1/ I am not conflating POS and function. 2/ Nowhere is "here" called a preposition. 3/ If "here" is a preposition, and therefore if "The level of maturity in argument here" is a prepositional phrase, where is the subject of the verb "be"? Only very rarely can a prepositional phrase be a subject. This makes no sense. Moreover, a preposition does not modify, it combines: ["Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition): A preposition […] combines with a noun phrase, this being called its complement, or sometimes object. A preposition comes before its complement;".

Comment: @DW256 It seems that the parallel is not exact because you use a pronoun which has a deictic function "This" can be deictic without that being true for "here" (ex;: As he handed the doctor another $500, “This here is for your cooperation and to know that you'll be on call in case we need you, for anything.”).

Comment: @LPH You are conflating them for the reason I gave earlier. Preposition is a word class (POS) and adverbial is a function.  I don't follow the rest of your comment. "The level of maturity in argument" is an NP headed by the noun "level". The PP "in argument" then modifies the nominal "level of maturity". "Here" is a certainly a preposition meaning "in this place"; See my answer.

Comment: @BillJ The OP themselves call "here" a prepositional phrase (see the OP: 'the presence of a second prepositional phrase, namely “here.”'; this is what I call inexact. I say nothing of "in argument", but it is clear to me that is a PP, no arguing about that. You must quote the very terms in my explanations that show what you are trying to say. I see no confusion on my part. I must say again that I do not believe that "here" is a preposition, specially as it found after; it would certainly have been called a postposition (see Wikipedia). No dictionary calls "here" a preposition.

Comment: This dictionary does [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/here), and so does CGEL. Incidentally, "here" is intransitive so it's best called simply a preposition, not a PP.

Comment: @LPH Works just as well with a head noun added in: _**Here** this thing is astounding_ / _This thing **here** is astounding_ / _This thing is astounding **here**_.

Comment: @BillJ True, there are now two references, but the wiktionary's has probably been pulled right out of H&P. Nevertheless, on top of what does not add up in the present discussion,  a preposition as they would have  it does not satisfy the logic of the definition;  in "the woman here is my wife" (Wiktionary example) the word "here" does not "show a relationship in space or time or a logical relationship between two or more people, places or things" ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prepositions)).

Comment: It doesn't need to; it's intransitive, though it's understood as something like "in this place".

Comment: @BillJ They are created a true jumble and they are not laying the foundations of their theory, nothing makes sense any more in the traditional approach. I can't go with H&P idea of what is a  preposition; it is contrary to too many accepted notions.

Comment: You haven't even read CGEL. This explains the reason you don't understand why it's a preposition. When you do, you may change your mind.

Comment: @BillJ What you read to me of CGEL is enough for me to form a first opinion; is there more in their work in the way of justifying such an extraordinary  extension? I don't believe so, I have the definite impression that they listen to a certain inspiration of theirs without taking into account age-long aqcuisitions in the domain of grammar. You can't do that.

Comment: @LPH Amongst other things, they look at the evidence, which is what we've all been telling you. Just borrow a copy from a library. They reject much of the analyses in the old Comprehensive.

Comment: @LPH Aaaargh: "no dictionary calls *here* a preposition". Are you joking? We don't use dictionaries for parts of speech! It's not what they're made for. And in any case,: [Wiktionary: *when*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page). One thing *here* definitely isn't is an adverb. No adverb morphology, occurs freely as the complement of the verb *BE*, can't be modified by *very*, can be  by both *right* and *straight*, semantically involves spatial deixis, can head a non-predicative adjunct. Every characteristic of a preposition, and absolutely no adverb type characteristics!!

Comment: @LPH [Here's why dictionaries haven't updated their parts of speech in a hundred years](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635). You say: *the word "here" does not "show a relationship in space or time or a logical relationship between two or more people, places or things"*. But that's not true, it's just with deictic prepositions, the 'anchor' is the speaker or listener or place being talked about, or the present time etc.

Comment: @LPH Would you like a copy of ACGEL so that you can read for yourself? Or if not, why don't you invest in a copy of [*A student's introduction to English grammar*](https://www.abebooks.co.uk/book-search/isbn/9780521612883/used/), very cheap now the second edition's out. Alternatively, you could try [Oxford Modern English Grammar](https://tinyurl.com/4afuhd6m). The latter was written by Bas Aarts, the current  head of the [Survey of English Usage](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/), which Randolph Quirk gave birth to. He worked with Q *et al* for many years and also gives, *here* as a Prep!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks first of all for all the pain you took in providing suggestions and references. // The Wiktionary link leads to the main page (I don't get the idea). // Here is what the _Cambridge English Grammar_ (CEG, Carter & McCarthy, 2006, about 1000 p.) says: "**Preposition, prepositional phrase, preposition stranding** Class of word used to express relationships between two events, things or people in terms of time […], space […] and other abstract relations […]".  It follows that the traditional understanding about prepositions is still very much alive. // ACGEL?

Comment: @LPH Sorry, should have been [this link here](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/here). And sorry again, should have been *TCGEL*. You already have *ACGEL*. The TEFL tome CEG is very handy for TEFL teachers in many respects. Unofrtunately its framework isn't very consistent, and disintegrates under pressure, as I found out when doing my DELTA and then later my MA in English Linguistics. I'm (somewhat irrationally)  still fond of it, even though I gave up using it quite a long time ago now.

Comment: @LPH Let me know if you want a copy of *TCGEL* (that's just my own personal acronym - not very nice of H&P to overwrite Q et al's title, although it could be taken as a form of flattery).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I was aware of this Wiktionary entry; it had been shown to me by user BillJ; it was labelled "adverb" prior to 2008. However, this is the [simple Wiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/here); the [English Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/here) does not mention "preposition", but only "adverb". //  As a matter of fact I obtained a copy of TCGEL yesterday from this [link](https://dokumen.tips/download/link/the-cambridge-grammar-of-the-english-language-567fec9810db6.html); it's a bad pdf copy that does not allow for Ctrl F search, (1/2)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  but nevertheless useful; I started reading the part on prepositions and I disagree already arguably on their choice of  the term "head" as categorizing the preposition in the prep. phrase. (There is IMO no criterion of centrality attached to the preposition.) The fact that H & P's points of view are found in the Simple Wiktionary and not in the English Wiktionary tends to confirm my idea that they try to aim at uniformisation and simplification, but that so doing  they indulge—deliberately or otherwise—in oversimplification. (2/2)

Comment: It's important to remember that this is not H&P, and nor is it the team of 14 world-renowned linguists who helped write CGEL, it's half of the serious linguistics community since the 1920's, starting with Otto Jespersen (arguably the world's greatest ever authority of English grammar), then later  Emonds, Jackendoff, Burton-Roberts, David Lee and many, many others. H&P are just letting you in on what's been known and discussed for over 100 years now! Anyhow, took me two or three readings to get on board myself ;-)